# Someone tries to use cancelled card

Tags: united-kingdom, scams, fraud, debit-card

In the UK, a debit card is stolen and the card's owner cancels the card. The thief tries to use the card for a contactless payment, but it is declined.

1. Would the bank have a record of this?
2. Would they know “a payment for X pound at time Y in store Z was declined”?
3. And would they tell the card owner?

I am just curious. This question is motivated by a situation shown on TV.

Comment: They probably wouldn't tell the card owner. They would tell the police, if they asked (which they probably wouldn't unless it was connected to Big Crimes somehow)

Comment: I'd assume that banks have a record of *literally everything*.

Answer (score 3):

If the card reader was on line at the time of the transaction, then the bank would be the ones declining the payment, so they would know.

Off-line card readers wouldn't know to decline the transaction at all.